# Memory Leak related with replaceChild

Tags: c++, xml, debugging, qt, memory-leaks

Here is source code of my function:

```
bool FieldModel::updateNode(QDomNode &node,const QString &parent){

  QDomElement rootOfTag;

  rootOfTag=fieldState.firstChild().firstChildElement(parent);

  qDebug()<<"Before"<<fieldState.toString();
  QDomNodeList sameTags=rootOfTag.elementsByTagName(node.firstChild().toElement().tagName());
  for(uint i=0;i<sameTags.length();i++){
      QDomNode nodeToReplace=sameTags.item(i);
      if(nodeToReplace.toElement().attribute("id")==node.firstChild().toElement().attribute("id")){
        nodeToReplace.parentNode().replaceChild(node,nodeToReplace);//Cause Memory Leak
        qDebug()<<"After"<<fieldState.toString();
        return true;
      }
  }

insertNode(node,parent);
return true;
}
```

Memory usage of this my program strictly increases, but when I removed line `nodeToReplace.parentNode().replaceChild(node,nodeToReplace);`, program uses stable amount of memory. 
I monitored `fieldState(QDomDocument)`, and it is not growing while I'm using `replaceChild` (I make small changes). What can be problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a QDom bug to me (which wouldn't surprise me too much, just submitted a patch to make "<a:>foo</a:>" not crash QDom). Try with a minimal example. If that still leaks and if are on Linux or OS X, you could run it in valgrind. Both the example and valgrind output would make a good bug report.

Edit: Would be interesting if removeChild() also leaks for you

Answer (score 1):

[The docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdomnode.html#replaceChild) say the call returns a reference to the old, replaced node on success:

> Returns a new reference to oldChild on success or a null node an failure.

I don't know QT well but I'd guess it assumes you'll clean the old node reference up?

Comment: No, there is no memory management needed using these classes. If there is memory leaked, that's a bug in QDom.

Comment: @Frank: If `replaceChild` returns a reference to the old child then the memory clearly isn't deleted at that point. I see the bit in the [`QDomDocument`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdomdocument.html#details) that says that memory for a node is destroyed when the last reference _and_ the dom document both go away. So it seems that until the `QDomDocument` is destroyed then old nodes will still be kicking around (even there are no more references to them).

Comment: @Troubadour: The signature is 

QDomNode QDomNode::replaceChild ( const QDomNode & newChild, const QDomNode & oldChild )

So there is nothing to release by the QDom user, the method returns a copy (albeit internally shared). I would expect the parent to remove oldChild from its children and not keep a reference to the then-removed child node. That doesn't make sense to me, and I don't see a way to explicitely release a node otherwise.

Comment: By referencing Troubadour words, I tried fieldstate.setContent(fieldState.toString()), and it solved my problem :), but it is very inefficient as it seems :(